# Apple Lossless (ALAC) encoder library in C, not C++

Tags: c, shared-libraries, codec

I have a small audio-project written in C, in which I would like to convert streamed PCM into ALAC.

I know there is the very large library "FFmpeg" which contains methods for this encoding, but FFmeg is oversized for my project.

There's also the [original ALAC-encoder available from Apple](http://alac.macosforge.org/), but it only has an interface written in C++.

Has anyone an address for a small, standalone ALAC-encoder written in C? It can be a shared library or just some C-files.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

[You can use LLVM to convert C++ code to C](http://llvm.org/releases/3.1/docs/FAQ.html#translatecxx) and [read some FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/mixing-c-and-cpp.html) that it's always a good thing.